# Ploting image in shiny R

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am starting to play with shinny apps and I am getting the following error when I try to run the code. The `output$myrgb` and `output$mynrg`variables are not being ploted.

I think the issue is realted to the way I am closing the brackets but I have tried several alternatives and the issue is still happening.

Any idea?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dbplyr)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

ui<-fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Calculation"),

  "SHORT DESCRIPTION ---- ",
  "Study area location",

  textInput(inputId = "mypath", label = "Path to Sentinel images"),
  leafletOutput("mymap",height = 1000),
  imageOutput(outputId = "myrgb"),
  imageOutput(outputId = "mynrg"),
  imageOutput(outputId = "ndvi")


)

server<-function(input, output) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng=-60.143, lat=-19.9052, zoom=7)
    m

    # Load  images
    bands<-c("B((0[2348]_10m)).jp2$")
    S2<-list.files(input$mypath, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".SAFE")
    S2<-list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern=bands)
    S2<-lapply(1:length(S2), function (x) {raster(S2[x])})
    S2<-stack(S2) 

    utmcoor<-SpatialPoints(cbind(xmin(S2[[1]]),ymax(S2[[1]])), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(S2[[1]]))) # prepare UTM coordinates matrix 
    longlatcoor<-spTransform(utmcoor,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) # converting
    utmcoor2<-SpatialPoints(cbind(xmax(S2[[1]]),ymin(S2[[1]])), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(S2[[1]]))) # prepare UTM coordinates matrix abajo derecha
    longlatcoor2<-spTransform(utmcoor2,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) # converting

    lng1<-xmin(longlatcoor) # extract coordinates to variable
    lng2<-xmin(longlatcoor2)
    lat1<-ymin(longlatcoor)
    lat2<-ymin(longlatcoor2)

    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% # Add coordinates to map
      addRectangles(
        lng1=lng1, lat1=lat1,
        lng2=lng2, lat2=lat2,
        fillColor = "transparent")
  }) 
  output$myrgb <- renderPlot({plotRGB(S2, r=3, g=2, b=1, scale=maxValue(S2[[1]]), stretch="lin")})
  output$mynrg <- renderPlot({plotRGB(S2, r=4, g=3, b=2, scale=maxValue(S2[[1]]), stretch="lin")})

  }

shinyApp( ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

EDIT ---
ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `plotOutput` instead of `imageOutput`?

Comment: yes and the same thing happens. If I move the `})` that are before `output$myrgb` and put them after `output$mynrg`, then a different error appears. (see edition in question). I think the problem is in the way in combining the different outputs but since I am new to shiny I cannot identify the problem

Comment: Your `S2` is defined inside `renderLeaflet`, therefore it does not exists outside `renderLeaflet`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But then, when `S2` is inside the `renderLeaflet` the images appear. But now it is the the map that does not appear and I get the error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to help without your files. But you should do something like that. Use a [reactive conductor](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) to pass the raster object.

```
server<-function(input, output) {

  Raster <- reactive({
    bands <- c("B((0[2348]_10m)).jp2$")
    S2 <- list.files(input$mypath, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".SAFE")
    S2 <- list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern=bands)
    S2 <- lapply(1:length(S2), function (x) {raster(S2[x])})
    stack(S2) 
  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng=-60.143, lat=-19.9052, zoom=7)

    S2 <- Raster()

    utmcoor<-SpatialPoints(cbind(xmin(S2[[1]]),ymax(S2[[1]])), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(S2[[1]]))) # prepare UTM coordinates matrix 
    longlatcoor<-spTransform(utmcoor,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) # converting
    utmcoor2<-SpatialPoints(cbind(xmax(S2[[1]]),ymin(S2[[1]])), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(S2[[1]]))) # prepare UTM coordinates matrix abajo derecha
    longlatcoor2<-spTransform(utmcoor2,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) # converting

    lng1<-xmin(longlatcoor) # extract coordinates to variable
    lng2<-xmin(longlatcoor2)
    lat1<-ymin(longlatcoor)
    lat2<-ymin(longlatcoor2)

    m %>% # Add coordinates to map
      addRectangles(
        lng1=lng1, lat1=lat1,
        lng2=lng2, lat2=lat2,
        fillColor = "transparent")
  }) 

  output$myrgb <- renderPlot({
    S2 <- Raster()
    plotRGB(S2, r=3, g=2, b=1, scale=maxValue(S2[[1]]), stretch="lin")
  })

  output$mynrg <- renderPlot({
    S2 <- Raster()
    plotRGB(S2, r=4, g=3, b=2, scale=maxValue(S2[[1]]), stretch="lin")
  })

}
```

Comment: mmm, okay I'll start by learning more about `reactive conductor`. Your code works but there was a small error. I replaced `m %>% # Add coordinates to map`  by  `leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% # Add coordinates to map`. Thank you

Comment: @GCGM Ok nice. I didn't understand why you define `m` at the beginning and then you don't use it. See the tuto I linked for the reactive conductors, it is very nice.